# How can you represent 4096 days with 12 bits?

Tags: storage

With 12 bits, apparently you can represent $2^{12}$ different days or 11 years. But how?

If you have 6 characters YYMMDD and each character represents 8 bits, how can this represent $2^{48}$ days?

Comment: IDK what you mean by "how", it's just the raw number, no tricks

Comment: I think you want to convert a day number to a particular year,month,date: https://planetcalc.com/7933/?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami The DEC PDP-10 (before DATE-75) only had 12 bits to represent dates. It could only represent dates between 1 Jan 1964 and 4 Jan 1975. So the computer would start counting from 1 Jan 1964 and convert the counter number to year, month and date?

Comment: @optim: do you know the reason for this $12$ ? As far as I can see it was a $36$ bits machine (!) Maybe legacy of the PDP-8 ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think it might be because PDP-10 used the TOPS-10 system. And TOPS-10 could only represent dates between 1 Jan 1964 and 4 Jan 1975.

Comment: @optim: I see. But this does not explain the $12$, does it ?

Comment: "So the computer would start counting from 1 Jan 1964 and convert the counter number to year, month and date?" - yes (of course, it does it in some efficient way). Using $k$ bts, you can represent any set of different $2^k$ objects, i.e. there is a mapping from $\{0, 1, \ldots, 2^k - 1\}$ to your set. It doesn't say anything about the mapping (and there are multiple possible mappings), but in this case you outlined the natural one. While there are many YYMMDD strings, you have a subset of only $2^{12}$ of them, and so $12$ bits are enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're right. This is from the lecture notes I'm reading: 'Digital Equipment Corporation’s date crisis occurred in 1975. The PDP-10 was a 36-bit mainframe
computer. It represented dates using a 12-bit format designed for the tiny PDP-8.'

Comment: @Dmitry For example, 0 would map to 1 Jan 1964, 1 would map to 2 Jan 1964 and so on right?

Comment: Yes. (I also forgot to say that the mapping must be surjective)

Answer (score 0):

$2^{12}$ days is indeed $11$ years, $2$ months and a few days (depending on the starting date). Convert from day number to YYMMDD date.

---

If I am right, there are $36524$ legal dates in the format YYMMDD in a complete century ($36525$ every fourth centuries).

The information content is about $15.16$ bits, which is $2.53$ bits per character. This comfortably fits in a `short uint`.

---

Using $48$ bits, you can encode dates for a little more than $7706417613$ centuries.

Comment: So the storage of the days and the storage of the actual date format are two seperate things? For some reason I thought they were the same thing. For the PDP-10, you would use 12 bits for the date (storing the days), wouldn't you only have 24 bits left?

Comment: @yes, but why are you asking that ?

Comment: Because how would the computer actually show the date in the YYMMDD format? Wouldn't you need at least 48 bits for that?

Comment: @optim: 6 bytes in the ASCII format. More (up to 24 bytes) using Unicode.

Comment: So the PDP-10 wouldn't be able to do this, right? As it doesn't have enough space.

Comment: @optim: it has plenty of space.

Comment: But how? You would need at least 6 bytes but the PDP-10 only has 24 bits left.

Comment: @optim: the PDP had at least 16 kilowords of memory.